# SVG Symbols not showing up in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

I have made sure the SVG path is set and that the path has SVG files:

```
Settings->Options->System->SVG Path > "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\svg"
```

In Layer Properties > Style Manager > Marker Symbols only 14 marker symbols show up...

I have reinstalled QGIS and delete registry keys and still no luck any ideas?

Only thing I can think of is that I installed a server version once to experiment with, I deleted it however maybe something from that install is still around?

Comment: Have you tested if the SVGs work on another machine? Have you tried adding a second SVG path with some simple SVG for test purposes?

Comment: @underdark No do not have access to another machine to test this issue. Adding a second SVG path with only 4 SVG's does not work. Importing from online source "works" but often images have lots of question marks.

Comment: Can you make one problematic SVG available for testing purposes?